# assets not being served in production with rails 4.1.0.rc1 nginx and unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm deploying a rails 4.1.0.rc1 app to production and everything appears to be working except that no assets are being served.

I am deploying to Ubuntu 12.04 on Nginx with Unicorn. Webrick is able to serve the assets with:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in production.rb.

Interestingly, under nginx/unicorn, the assets are being referenced without the fingerprint. I.e
/assets/application.css
instead of
/assets/application-2c83bb5c879fd170625884df41e4b778.css

Of course, when nginx goes to serve the asset, it doesn't exist. This is only an issue with the unicorn/nginx setup, under webrick as production (locally and on the server) the correct filename is present and the asset is correctly served up.

Other than the OS specific parts, I have been following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5 .

**config/unicorn.rb**

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/var/www/citysquares"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/var/www/citysquares/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/var/www/citysquares/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/www/citysquares/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
listen "/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.citysquares.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.citysquares.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {


    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    #root /root/citysquares/public;
    root /var/www/citysquares/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Any and all help appreciated, this has me stumped!

Comment: Did you precompile the assets?

Comment: Thanks for responding, yes I did. I can see the compiled assets and webrick is able to serve them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the "assets" block in your config and restart nginx

```
server {
  # . . .
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  # . . .
}
```

Comment: I added that block directly above 'error_page', restarted and still no luck. The assets are still showing in page source without the fingerprint.